# Per platform dependencies

Tags: dart, flutter, dependencies

I need to include a dependency only for the Android version, is it possible? And if so can something similar to #if DEBUG #else be used to add it in some .dart files only for the android version of the app?

Comment: No. There is no way to have dependencies only for one platform.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply